# Apply callback to all instances of Magnific Popup?

Tags: magnific-popup

Is there a way to bind an event callback so that it's called for all instances of Magnific Popup? On a site I'm building several elements have fixed position and "jump" when the main browser scrollbar disappears. I want to set a callback to add padding for those elements before any popup is opened, and remove the padding when the popup is closed. I don't want to re-use the callbacks every time I initialize Magnific Popup – I'd rather set one set of callbacks that is run every time Magnific opens and closes a popup.

My first thought was to use event delegation and bind pretty high in the document tree. I was trying to bind to the `mfpOpen` event and listen on the `BODY` tag, but it doesn't seem like the event bubbles. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Events are dispatched only on target element or on document (if target element is not present).

But you may override open function globally using prototype, e.g.:

```
$.magnificPopup.instance.open = function(data) {

    console.log('before open anything');

    $.magnificPopup.proto.open.call(this,data);

    console.log('after open anything');
};
```

You may do the same thing with `close` function (it doesn't have any arguments).

Comment: Can I hook into an event when the next or previous gallery item is shown?